# Deal with open intervals when finding if a given date range is inside another date range?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the number of seconds a user has had his/her account enabled during a specific 7 day time period.

This can be easily done using `TIMEDIFF` - but what makes this tricky (and not answered anywhere else):

[A] The account was enabled once our time period started (`id` 2) and should be considered enabled since start date.

[B] There is no `enabled_end` set for `id` 5, meaning account is currently enabled and should be considered enabled until end date.

Her is the basic query:

`SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(enabled_end, enabled_start)))) AS total_seconds from logs WHERE user_id = '123' and enabled_start >= '2022-04-22 00:00:00' and enabled_end <= '2022-04-27 23:59:59'`

So above query will fail to include `id` 2 as described in [A] and `id` 5 as described in [B]

| id | user_id | enabled_start | enabled_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 123 | 2022-04-26 12:13:38 | NULL (=account is still enabled) |
| 4 | 123 | 2022-04-25 15:22:36 | 2022-04-25 17:32:11 |
| 3 | 123 | 2022-04-24 11:16:46 | 2022-04-25 05:10:08 |
| 2 | 123 | 2022-04-15 14:44:00 | 2022-04-23 10:58:53 |
| 1 | 123 | 2022-03-29 16:44:15 | 2022-04-04 11:22:39 |
| 0 | 123 | 2022-03-24 13:44:15 | 2022-03-25 09:11:39 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Akina pointed out:

- If `enabled_end` is NULL then COALESCE returns range end.
- If `enabled_end` is out of the range then LEAST returns range end.
- In all other cases `enabled_end` value is returned.
- If `enabled_start` is out of the range then GREATEST returns range start.

However this didn't solve the issue in my question [A] that the account was enabled once our time period started (id 2) and should be considered enabled from the start date.

I found two different approaches to determine whether two date ranges overlap:

- [(StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/2157236)
- Alternate way: If two segments [a, b] and [c, d] intersect each other: [(a-d)*(b-c) <= 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27430668/2157236)

Also, if `enabled_end` is NULL, we only want to include it if `enabled_start` is less than the end date.

All together it resulted in this query (make sure dates are in the Y-m-d H:i:s format) - works like a charm!

```
SELECT sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 
    
GREATEST(enabled_start, TIMESTAMP '2022-04-22 00:00:00'),
    
LEAST(COALESCE(enabled_end, TIMESTAMP '2022-04-28 00:00:00'), TIMESTAMP '2022-04-28 00:00:00'))
    
) as total_seconds FROM logs 

WHERE

((enabled_start <= '2022-04-28 00:00:00') and (enabled_end >= '2022-04-22 00:00:00') OR

enabled_end IS NULL and enabled_start < '2022-04-28 00:00:00')

and enabled_start IS NOT NULL
    
and user_id = '123' group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sql
TIMEDIFF(LEAST(COALESCE(enabled_end, TIMESTAMP '2022-04-27 23:59:59'), TIMESTAMP '2022-04-27 23:59:59'))
```

- If `enabled_end` is NULL then COALESCE returns range end.
- If `enabled_end` is out of the range then LEAST returns range end.
- In all other cases `enabled_end` value is returned.

`TIMESTAMP` specifier causes datetime compare. You may remove it - in this case the values will be compared as strings (in this case the datetime literal must be complete, i.e. it must contain leading zeros for 1-digit part values).

Comment: Thanks! Based on your inputs, I created this query that successfully handles the end date. Now how do we modify this to take into account the problem with start date as described in [A]?


```select sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, enabled_start, LEAST(COALESCE(enabled_end, TIMESTAMP '2022-04-27 23:59:59'), TIMESTAMP '2022-04-27 23:59:59'))) as total_seconds from logs where enabled_start >= '2022-04-22 00:00:00' and (enabled_end <= '2022-04-27 23:59:59'' OR enabled_end IS NULL) and user_id = '123' group by user_id```

Comment: @Carl The same. But you must use GREATEST instead of LEAST and, if starting time cannot be NULL, do not need in COALESCE.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Akina - I just posted the query in full (taking into account other aspects) as a new answer.